# Performantly update table with 2 million rows with Postgres/PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables:

- `properties` (geo_point POINT, locality_id INTEGER, neighborhood_id INTEGER, id UUID)
- `places_temp` (id INTEGER, poly GEOMETRY, placetype TEXT)

Note: all columns in `places_temp` are indexed.

`properties` has ~2 million rows and I would like to:

- update `locality_id` and `neighborhood_id` for each row in `properties` with the `id` from `places_temp` where `properties.geo_point` is contained by a polygon in `places_temp.poly`

Whatever I do it just seems to hang for hours within which time I don't know if it's working, the connection is lost, etc.

Any thoughts on how to do this performantly?

My query:

```sql
  -- drop indexes on locality_id and neighborhood_id to speed up update
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_properties_locality_id;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_properties_neighborhood_id;
  -- for each property find the locality and neighborhood
  UPDATE
    properties
  SET
    locality_id = (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        places_temp
      WHERE
        placetype = 'locality'
        -- check if geo_point is contained by polygon. geo_point is stored as SRID 26910 so must be
        -- transformed first
        AND st_intersects (st_transform (geo_point, 4326), poly)
      LIMIT 1),
  neighborhood_id = (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      places_temp
    WHERE
      placetype = 'neighbourhood'
      -- check if geo_point is contained by polygon. geo_point is stored as SRID 26910 so must be
      -- transformed first
      AND st_intersects (st_transform (geo_point, 4326), poly)
    LIMIT 1);
  -- Add indexes back after update
  CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_properties_locality_id ON properties (locality_id);
  CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_properties_neighborhood_id ON properties (neighborhood_id);
```

Comment: I have no idea, but its a fascinating question.... have you read this: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

Comment: @wildplasser the limit is just because there might be multiple overlapping polygons; the data isn't perfect. For my purposes I'm happy to just take the first one that matches.

Comment: But: why do you use a scalar subquery? Just because of the limit?

Comment: @Cargo23 thanks - yes I did. I updated the question to call out that I am using geospatial indexes.

Comment: @wildplasser - sorry my SQL skills are pretty basic. If there's a better way to do it I'd love to hear :). Basically I was just trying to get a single id from the subquery that I could use to update the column value: locality_id and neighborhood_id, respectively. Is there a better way?

Comment: What does "performantly" mean?  How quickly are you wanting it to run?

Comment: For performance, there should be an index on the geo-columns geo_point and poly.

Comment: @wildplasser there are. Updated the question.

Comment: @AndyLester well it seems to go for hours and hours and never complete. I left it overnight and wasn't done by morning. There's no indication of progress so I don't know what's going on behind the scenes...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX properties_point_idx ON properties USING gist (geo_point);
CREATE INDEX places_temp_poly_idx ON places_temp USING gist (poly);

UPDATE properties p
SET locality_id = x.id
FROM ( SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER () rn
        FROM places_temp t 
        WHERE t.placetype = 'locality'
        AND st_intersects (st_transform (p.geo_point, 4326), t.poly)
        )x
WHERE x.rn = 1
      ;
```

And similar for the other field (you could combine them into one query)

Comment: Thanks. Mind explaining why this would be faster?

Comment: Only because of the indexes. (but I cannot test from here) The rest is a matter of style, I am afraid...

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Yeah I do have indexes on those columns but thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        UPDATE
      properties
   SET
    locality_id =t.id, neighbourhood_id
    =t.id
    From(
    SELECT
    id
    FROM
    places_temp
  WHERE
    placetype in ('locality',  
   'neighbourhood') 
    AND st_intersects (st_transform 
   (geo_point, 4326), poly)
  LIMIT 1)) t
```